# Node.js Express – How to Get Raw Data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, raw-data

I have an Express server that manages a login form page:

```
const app = express();

// section A
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
app.post('/login', userController.postLogin);
```

It runs correctly.

Then I have another controller that reads RAW DATA:

```
// section B
const concat = require('concat-stream');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.pipe(concat(function(data: any) {
    req.body = data;
    next();
  }));
});

app.post('*', otherController.post);

export let post = (req: any, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.body); //i see RAW DATA
  res.end('n');
}
```

It also works well.

But if I join the two sections, the second section stops working.

How can I say to use the `req.pipe` only for the section B?

Comment: you can set req.bodyRaw = data;  and then use it

Comment: I dont think that this is the right solution see this https://coderwall.com/p/qrjfcw/capture-raw-post-body-in-express-js Have you an example?

Answer (score 1):

This middleware (like virtually every other middleware out there), does not have a way to exclude it from certain requests, since the method in which users would desire to exclude can be anything--url, header, query string, loaded user, and more. Instead middleware places the logic of pathing on you: either (a) explicitly include it (which means placing on the routes, as recommended in our documentation) or (b) wrap the middleware with your own exclusion logic:

```
const parseExtend = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
app.use((req, res, next) => shouldParseRequest(req) ? parseExtend(req, res, next) : next());

/* implement shouldParseRequest (req) to return false for whatever you want to not parse json for */
```